# yii2 unable to delete a file using unlink

Tags: php, yii2, delete-file

I am trying to use unlink to delete a file I currecntly have the below code:

```
unlink(Yii::getAlias('@webroot') . $userprofile->avatar);
```

The path is correct as I have used echo within the view to check and it point to the correct file that I wish to delete, however I get the below error:

```
unlink(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/advanced/Final Prototype): Operation not permitted
```

Could this be a permissions thing in terms of not being the owner if so how can I check, do I need to do chmod on the file or some directories?

**Note**: Working on Mac OS X and using MAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the owner of web directory and its files to your web server user (e.g. `www-data` for apache).

In apache you can find the user and group on *inx systems, from `httpd.conf` by looking for `User` or `Group`. For example my `httpd.conf` file on arch linux is:

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
 #
 # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
 # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
 #
 # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
 # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
 # running httpd, as with most system services.
 #
 User http
 Group http  
</IfModule>
```

So with this config you can run `chown -R http:http web` on root of Yii project.

If the problem was persistent, also you need to change permissions of web folder for having write rule on user and group (`chmod -R 755 web` may be a temporary solution for this. You must move your files to an upload folder and change permission of that to `755`).